# php, перфекционизм

Tags: php, алгоритм, инспекция-кода

Есть бэкенд на PHP, обслуживающий разные запросы и возвращающие json.

Точка входа(упрощенно):

```
try {
    switch ($method) {
        case 'login':
            $call = new Login($data);
            break;
        case 'list':
            $call = new List($data);
            break;
        default:
            $call = new WrongMethod($data);
    }
    $out  = ['r' => $call(),'n' => (string)Error::OK,'e' => ''];
} catch (Error $e) {
    $out = [
        'r' => $call::defaultResult())),
        'n' => (string)$e->getCode(),
        'e' => $e->getMessage()
    ];
}
print_r(json_encode($out, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE), false);
```

Уже увидели ошибку? ;)

**Проблема:** 
`$call::defaultResult()` - в блоке `catch` объект `$call` не определен.

Все классы пуляют `Error extends Exception` и реализуют интерфейс

```
interface Call {
    public function __construct(array $data);
    public function __invoke();
    public static function defaultResult();
}
```

`defaultResult` нужен потому, что `_invoke` может вернуть скаляр, обычный массив либо ассоциативный массив и если при ошибке использовать значение какого-то одного типа, то фронт споткнется на десериализации. То есть мне нужно гарантированно получить в блоке `catch` такую же структуру поля `'r'`, как и в блоке `try`

Я вижу два варианта решения:

1. Вынести из конструктора все, что может бросить исключение. Такой подход не нравится тем, что у меня в конструкторах исключительно проверка входных данных на валидность и их приведение в случае необходимости. ИМХО этому функционалу самое место в конструкторе.
2. Перейти на тёмную сторону и сделать как-то так:

   (Этот вариант мне вообще не нравится. Прям вызывает дискомфорт и потерю аппетита.)

   ```
   function getMethodClass($method) {
       switch ($method) {
           case 'login':
               return "Login";
           case 'list':
               return "GetList";
           default:
               return "WrongMethod";
       }
   }
   $className = $callsNameSpace."\\" . getMethodClass($method);
   try {
       $call = new $className($data);
   ...
   } catch (Error $e) {
       $out = ['r' => call_user_func(array($className, 'defaultResult')),
   ...
   }
   ```

**Внимание, вопрос!**

Может я не прав относительно своих фобий и первый(или второй) вариант вполне себе хорош?

Может я заработался и не вижу простого и очевидного решения? Такого чтоб и работало нормально и с души не воротило?

**UPD** PHP 5.6

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вы забыли о еще одном очень-очень важном моменте. В первом вашем варианте конструкция:

```
$call::defaultResult()
```

невалидна (как минимум, идеологически). Фактически вы пытаетесь вызвать метод класса у экземпляра, что лишено смысла.

С учетом этого, второй ваш вариант намного лучше. Хотя я немного причесал бы его (в примере ниже использую PHP 5.5+):

```
$map = [
    'login' => Login::class,
    'list' => List::class,
];
$class_name = isset($map[$method]) ? $map[$method] : WrongMethod::class;

try {
    $call = new $class_name($data);
    // ...
} catch (Error $e) {
    $out = ['r' => $class_name::defaultResult()];
}
```

**Замечание:**

Для ошибок валидации входных данных в PHP традиционно используется `\InvalidArgumentException` и его подклассы. А `\Error` - это специальный класс *ошибок* введенный в PHP7. Возможно стоит немного изменить имя вашего класса исключений, чтобы повысить читаемость кода и избежать двусмысленности после перехода на PHP7.

Comment: Ну зачем везде тенарные операторы. И вроде вопрос не как вызвать, а как провалидировать данные

Comment: @Naumov "везде" - это в одном месте? Используйте `if` если он вам больше нравится. Ну и вопрос не про валидацию, а про code-review.

Comment: ok привидите кодинг стандарт где рекомендуеться использовать тенарные операторы?

Comment: @Naumov, ok, приведите общепринятый стиль кодирования где **не рекомендуется** этого делать. Более того, у ТС похоже вообще PHP7, а раз так, то вместо `isset() ?:` можно использовать `??` что в разы нагляднее `if`.

Comment: `$call::defaultResult()` вполне валидная конструкция. Смысл же простой - мы заранее не знаем, у какого класса этот метод будет вызываться. Впрочем его вполне можно сделать и не статическим - на суть вопроса это не повлияет. У меня PHP 5.6. За нотацию ::class спасибо - не знал :)

Comment: `$call::defaultResult()` - идеологически не обоснован (хотя и работает) ;)

Comment: @rjhdby, а еще меня смутил класс `Error`. Думал у вас php7. Выкинул лишнее замечание и привел код к php5.5+

Comment: @DmitriySimushev не-не-не, очень правильно смутил. Когда нибудь же придется на PHP7 переползать, так что лучше сейчас, от греха, переименую.

Comment: @DmitriySimushev кстати, а вот использование подобного массива не приведет к тому, что все эти классы подгрузятся и скомпилируются во время исполнения скрипта?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/45461/discussion-between-dmitriy-simushev-and-rjhdby).