# php, накладные расходы на заданные, но не использованные классы

Tags: php, производительность, теория

[По мотивам другого вопроса](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/566867/php-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%84%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BC)

Вопрос в контексте PHP 5.5+ и 7

Существует скрипт, эдакий оркестратор, который, в зависимости от входных параметров, инстанцирует разные классы.

Я знаю три принципиально разных подхода для реализации.

Первый:

```
switch ($method) {
    case 'login':
        $call = new Login($data);
        break;
    case 'list':
        $call = new List($data);
        break;
    default:
        $call = new WrongMethod($data);
}
```

Второй:

```
$methods = [
    'login'   => 'Login',
    'list'    => 'GetList',
];
$className = isset($methods[ $method ]) ? $methods[ $method ] : 'WrongMethod';
$call = new $className($data);
```

Третий(предложенный Dmitriy Simushev):

```
$methods = [
    'login'   => Login::class,
    'list'    => GetList::class,
];
$className = isset($methods[ $method ]) ? $methods[ $method ] : WrongMethod::class;
$call = new $className($data);
```

**Что можете сказать за утилизацию памяти и скорость работы каждого из них?** (Подозреваю, что по памяти выиграет второй, но доказать не могу)

Comment: есть только один надежный способ - профилироваь и делать бенчмарк. Или Вы хотите, что бы это сделали за Вас?

Comment: @KoVadim есть способ гораздо более надежный - знать как работает компилятор php. Собственно вопрос к тем, кто знает. Ну либо к тем, кто уже задавался подобным вопросам, профилировал и делал бенчмарки.

Comment: Нет, этот способ не надежнее, потому что таких людей очень мало. Есть много людей, кто думает, что знает, но они заблуждаются.

Но, во первых, там интерпретатор, а вторых, оно по разному может работать на разном железе и разных версиях пхп.

Вы точно уверены, что не хотите профилировать/бенчмаркать?

Comment: @KoVadim Вообще то там компилятор в байт-код, который уже интерпритируется. ИМХО мой вопрос больше относится именно к первой части этого процесса, то есть компиляции. Вопрос, лично для меня на момент сейчас, представляет чисто академический интерес. Если знатоков не найдется, тогда возможно.

Comment: в любом интерпретаторе так или иначе есть преобразование в удобное представление. Но это ещё не дает язык компилируемым:)

Если совсем лень делать бенчмарки - сходите на сайт https://3v4l.org - там можно ввести свой пример и посмотреть, на него "поглубже".

Comment: @KoVadim "компиляция - трансляция программы, составленной на исходном языке высокого уровня, в эквивалентную программу на низкоуровневом языке". Таки он компилятор ;) За ссылку спасибо, пойду смотреть

Comment: осталось выяснить, является ли байткод низкоуровневым языком:)

Comment: @KoVadim ну уж всяко ниже php-скрипта. Эдак мы дойдем до того, что Java тоже интерпретатор. :)

Comment: да, это так и есть, но в java есть немножечко компиляции на уровне виртуальной машины - части кода могут преобразовываться в прямые  инструкции для процессора. Байт код - это просто удобное представление программы для интерпретатора.

Comment: @rjhdby, в java применяется jit компиляция (just in time). Когда полученных из исходников байткод запускается на конктретном устройстве, то jvm (вроде) компилирует по мере необходимости байткод в машинный код под конкретное устройство. Так что интерпретируемым как-то язык не поворачивается джаву назвать. В пхп подход другой.

Comment: @KoVadim создатели java с вами не согласны и даже, из вредности, назвали модуль преобразования в байт-код "Java programming language compiler" aka javac. Но, чувствую, что мы потихоньку скатываемся в holywar, посему предлагаю остановиться. :)

Comment: Про утилизацию памяти: пара загруженных классов не утилизируют заметно память. Про скорость: физическая загрузка классов потребует обращения к диску, если у вас все по PSR, но на это я тоже не обращал бы внимания. Оптимизировать PHP на этом уровне бессмысленно, потому что если скорость настолько важна, для качественных изменений проще взять качественно другую платформу (я не про то что PHP хуже чего-то, я про языки, которым не нужны накладные расходы на динамическую типизацию и нтерпретацию). Второй вариант отвратителен.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Провел следующий эксперимент.

Создал 4 одинаковых класса A,B,C,D. Такого типа:

```
class A 
    {
        private $b;
        public function __construct() {
            for($i=0;$i<100000;$i++) $b[] = $i;
        }
    }
```

И оркестратор:

```
spl_autoload_register(
    function ($class) {
        include_once($class . ".php");
    }
);

$start = microtime(true);
//Тут пример только одного из вариантов, что бы было представление о структуре скрипта
$map = [
    '1' => 'A',
    '2' => 'B',
    '3' => 'C',
    '4' => 'D'
];
$m   = (string)rand(1, 4);
$a = new $map[$m]();

echo "Time: " . (microtime(true) - $start) . "s<br>";
echo "RAM script usage: " . (memory_get_peak_usage(false) / 1024 / 1024) . " MiB<br>";
echo "RAM allocated: " . (memory_get_peak_usage(true) / 1024 / 1024) . " MiB<br>";
var_dump(preg_grep("/^.$/",get_declared_classes()));
```

Запустил каждый из вариантов по нескольку раз, прогрева ради.

Собственно по всем трем вариантам картина в среднем одинаковая.

```
Time: 0.093303s
RAM script usage: 14.208557128906 MiB
RAM allocated: 14.5 MiB
array (size=1)
  133 => string 'B' (length=1)
```

Реально подгружается только один класс, тот, который попадает в ветку исполнения.

Answer (score 1):

Я бы предложил малость другой вариант обозвать соответственно методу

```
'login' => 'Login'
'getList' => 'GetList'
```

и инстацировать так

```
$className = ucfirst($method);
if(class_exists($className)) {
     new $className($data);
} else {
     new WrongMethod($data);
}
```

По теории сложности алгоритмов все 3-ри выше приведённых метода одинаковы так же как и приведённый мной.

Comment: Насколько я понимаю, использовать `class_exists` с `autoload` и пространствами имен - то еще удовольствие. Да и поддерживать точную связку "имя метода" == "имя класса", тоже налагает некоторые ограничения, что на бэк, что на фронт.

Comment: Если честно в любом случае автоматический инстанс класса не очень так как, не очевидно какой класс находиться перед тобой в любой момент программы.